# Doctrine mapping import views

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I've many views in my Database. I want to mapping:import to generate Entitys from this views.
But when I was tried this command :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity
```

I've no new Entity, only from only real table "migration_versions" ...

Do you know how to generate many Entity from many views in Database ?
Thank a lot

I use Symfony 5.0

Comment: https://prnt.sc/r2dzbm https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Comment: My .env is correct, when I set doctrine:status it create table "migration_versions" in my database. 
But none of views are create in Entities

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Imagine taht you have a view MYVIEW.

1.- Create a new view: CREATE VIEW MYVIEW_TEMP AS SELECT * FROM MYVIEW

2.- Drop the original view: DROP VIEW MYVIEW

3. - Create a new table MYVIEW: CREATE TABLE MYVIEW AS SELECT * FROM MYVIEW_TEMP

4.- Create a INDEX PRIMARY KEY in table MYVIEW.

5.- Import with: php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity

6.- Drop table: DROP TABLE MYVIEW

7.- CREATE VIEW MYVIEW AS SELECT * FROM MYVIEW_TEMP

8.- DROP VIEW MYVIEW_TEMP

So, you cheated Symfony